# Creating sub site in feature receiver does not work always in sandbox solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, feature-activation, sub-site

I have created a sandbox solution in which there is one feature for creating two sub-sites.  In the event receiver of that feature I have created two sites programmatically.

The code is as per below:

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        SPWeb currentWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;


        currentWeb.Webs.Add("Blog", "Blogs", "", (uint)1033, "BLOG#0", false, false);
        currentWeb.Webs.Add("COMMUNITY", "Community", "", (uint)1033, "COMMUNITY#0", false, false);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    { }
```

The feature is placed in the web template, under `<WebFeatures>`.  But after creating site from the web template sometimes sub  sites are created and sometimes not created.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable social feature at the site collection level in order to create a community subsite.

Answer (score 0):

Use parent as `SPSite`

```
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
using (SPWeb currentWeb = site.RootWeb)
{ }
```